# EPPluse complex hyperlink crashing excel file

Tags: c#, hyperlink, epplus

I am using eppluse library for creating reports in c#.
Reports contain millions of urls that I have to show as hyperlink / clicable links.
Currently, everything is working but some URLs is breaking my Reports.xlsx file.
[Error Snap in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1fan.png)

Code sample:

```
for (var j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
{
    // Format values before printing
    object cellValue = ParseString(values[j].Replace("\"", ""));

    // Check for urls and conver to hyperlinks
    if (cellValue.GetType().Name.ToLower() == "uri")
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(Uri.EscapeUriString(cellValue.ToString().Replace("[", "%5B").Replace("]", "%5D"))) { Display = "Link" };
        worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].StyleName = hyperLinkStyle.Name;
    }
    else
    {
        worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Value = cellValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity... Why do you need a sheet with millions of clickable url's? Who is gonna click'em all?

Comment: Actually, our client's products are on different e-commerce sites and we check violations of product and provide a report which contains actual product URLs. Sometimes that is a very huge report which contains millions of urls and its creating issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for help following solution worked at the moment.
I am not sure how long it going works, But currently working smoothly.

```
string url = Uri.EscapeUriString(cellValue.ToString().Replace("[", "%5B").Replace("]", "%5D"));
        if (cellValue.ToString().Length < 256)
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Formula = string.Format("HYPERLINK(\"{0}\",\"{1}\")", url, "Link");
        }
        else
        {
            worksheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(url) { Display = "Link" };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code. There is nothing wrong with it. But luck would have it that I made a small mistake in the below snippet for testing. As it is now it creates a hyperlink for every filled cell in the sheet.

```
for (int col = 1; col <= ws.Dimension.End.Column; col++)
{
    ws.Column(col).Width = ws.Column(col).Width + 1;

    for (var j = 1; j <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; j++)
    {
        ws.Cells[col, j].Hyperlink = new ExcelHyperLink(Uri.EscapeUriString("http://www.google.nl".Replace("[", "%5B").Replace("]", "%5D"))) { Display = "Link" };
    }
}
```

But the first time I ran that snippet with the following `Cells[col + 1, j + 1]`. This created a completely filled out excel sheet since in the loop it shifted `Dimension.End` every time. But when the sheet was full it did generate the same error you got. That the sheet was corrupted.

In conclusion it would seem that either Excel or EPPlus cannot handle HyperLinks beyond a certain number...

Comment: No, Actually, I have provided here only the core part of my function.
It's working for most of the time but it fails for some critical URLs/ illegal characters URL. Cells[col + 1, j + 1] this is for skipping the first line that I have already added in excel as a header. 
And I have added ws.Cells[col, j].Hyperlink = new Uri(value); after checking value is a valid URL otherwise I only set ws.Cells[col, j].value = value;